# wicket spring hibernate getting started

Tags: spring, hibernate, maven, wicket, maven-archetype

I am looking for an archtype to create a Maven project based on

- Wicket 6.0.0
- Spring 3.2
- Hibernate 4 (annotation based)

All the examples I have seen (I have been looking for the last 4 hr) are with different versions and when I have tried to change versions step by step after the 4th bug I start using another archetype cause the time spent was significant.

If anyone got a base "getting stated " project using the last I would like you to show me how to do it please.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

run mvn achetype:generate -Dfilter=wicket

There's one from **org.xaloon** (7th in my list) that uses **spring/jpa/wicket**. You can configure/use Hibernate with JPA semantics (Spring Data?), or tweak the archetype. Maybe [this](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/hibernate-4.0.1-pom.xml) would help.